# Adding Imports To addon.xml for Kodi

Tags: python, xml, kodi

What is the syntax for adding imports to Kodi addon.xml file? I am trying to use pythons requests, and I get this error:

```
07:54:13.435 T:123145511706624   ERROR: EXCEPTION Thrown (PythonToCppException) : -->Python callback/script returned the following error<--
                                             - NOTE: IGNORING THIS CAN LEAD TO MEMORY LEAKS!
                                            Error Type: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>
                                            Error Contents: No module named requests
                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
                                              File "//Kodi/addons/bingewave.venues/addon.py", line 8, in <module>
                                                import requests
                                            ImportError: No module named requests
                                            -->End of Python script error report<--
```

Now I noticed Kodi has a lot of libraries built into the platform that include these: http://kodi.wiki/view/Category:Add-on_libraries/modules

Currently in my add-on xml, I have this:

```
<addon id="example" name="Example" version="1.0.4" provider-name="zag">
    <requires>
        <import addon="xbmc.python" version="2.14.0"/>
    </requires>
    <extension point="xbmc.python.script" library="addon.py">
        <provides>executable</provides>
    </extension>
</addon>
```

What is the syntax for importing more modules like requests?

Comment: Isn't it already available? http://kodi.wiki/view/add-on:requests

Comment: Yes, but I think it has to be imported

Comment: Something like `<import addon="script.module.requests"`?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `<requires>` defintion `<import addon="script.module.requests" version="2.12.4"/>`

It won't resolve this for your local dev enviroment, it will only be resolved if you install the addon via an zip or from an addon repo. So just setting it and starting kodi will likly crash your addon anyway.
If your looking for the module to install to for your dev enviroment look here http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/xbmc/addons/krypton/script.module.requests/